# Is it possible to get the name of AWS EMR step currently executing without going to console

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

If there are 3 steps  that are executed in EMR, is it possible to know which step is currently executing, using shell script.

I am able to get current state of the EMR cluster, using this:

```
`aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id ${cluster_id} | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["Cluster"]["Status"]["State"]'`
```

but I am not able to get the information about the name of step currently executing, is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list-steps` option in the AWS CLI for EMR returns each step. It can be filtered to only return the steps in a certain state: `aws emr list-steps --step-states "RUNNING"`

(See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/list-steps.html)